# Remove time component from TimeInterval in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swift3

I have a time component coming from a Json. I am trying to group objects according to their time posted.

I have a time interval like `1540432146` which is a double.

I am converting it to Date type using

```
guard let timeInMilliseconds = lastUpdateOn as? Double else {return NSDate()}
    let timeInSeconds = timeInMilliseconds / 100000

    print(timeInSeconds)
    // get the Date
    let dateTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSeconds)
```

Hence I am getting `2018-10-25 10:54:20.325076+0900` as the output.

Is it possible to remove the Time component of this and again converting the Date type back to TimeIntervalSincel1970 as I will using it later to sort my elements in an array and it would be easier to compare Double

```
func getTime(lastUpdateOn:Any) -> NSDate{

    guard let timeInMilliseconds = lastUpdateOn as? Double else {return NSDate()}
    let timeInSeconds = timeInMilliseconds / 100000
    // get the Date
    let dateTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInSeconds)

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let datenew = dateFormatter.string(from: dateTime as Date)

    let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: datenew)
     print(newDate)
    return dateTime
}
```

This is the function I tried but it returns value `(1970-06-27 15:00:00 +0000)` always. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: One second has 1000 milliseconds, not  100000.

Comment: You sir were right, I did not realize it , silly mistake. Thank you for pointing out. It seems to work fine now.

Comment: You should use `Date` in Swift, not `NSDate` and you can easily compare `Date`s.  You should only convert back to a string when you want to display the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only goal is to compare different dates to see which one comes first, simply convert the Int Unix Timestamps from your JSON to `Date` objects with:

```
let aDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(timestamp)/1000.0)
```

You can compare `Date` objects directly using `>`, `=`, `<`, etc, and the result will compare the dates down to the millisecond.

You can also compare your Unix timestamp values directly and the results will be identical to comparing timestamps that you've converted to `Date` objects.

If you want to compare Date objects just by month/day/year, its more complicated.

A Cocoa `Date` **ALWAYS** represents an instant in time, all over the world. Internally, it's represented as a number of seconds since the iOS "epoch date" (midnight on January 1st, 2001 in UTC) Unix uses a different epoch date, but using "timeIntervalSince1970" and it's variants lets you work with Cocoa `Date` objects and Unix epoch dates.

There is no such thing as a Date "without a time component". There are various ways you could "normalize" your dates: You can convert a date to a date **string** that only has the month/day/year; you can force all Date values to exactly midnight on their month/day/year in a given timezone, or you could extract month/day/year `DateComponents` from your `Date`. (Search on "DateComponents" in the Xcode help system, and also search for "DateComponents" in the `Calendar` class reference, as many of the functions that let you do calculations on `Dates` and `DateComponents` are provided by the `Calendar` class.)

Note that the day/month/year that a Unix numeric timestamp falls on is often different depending on your time zone. Right now it's 22:47 EDT on 24 October here in the DC suburbs. I just computed the Unix timestamp for the current time and got 1540435644000. In Japan, 1540435644000 is 25 October. (From my perspective, it's already tomorrow in Japan).   So 2 Unix timestamps might be on the same day/month/year in Japan but on different day/month/years where I live, or visa-versa.